# Excel formula for nested IF statements

Tags: excel, nested-if

I have 4 products that go on the same machine. The machine has different cycle time for each product. Now if the manager puts in the quantity manufactured against a part (could be 0), it should populate the respective cycle time.

I could get the cycle times if manager puts a non zero number. My problem is, I am not able to get it to work for production = 0.

I have attached snapshot of the excel for ease o understanding.
[image: Excel snapshot]

Here is the excel formula that I wrote. Sheet1 is the worksheet from where I am pulling the cycle times.

IF(F13=0,Sheet1!C5,IF(Days!G13=0,Sheet1!E5,IF(Days!H13=0,Sheet1!G5,IF(Days!I13=0,Sheet1!I5,(IFERROR(((F13*Sheet1!C5)+(Days!G13*Sheet1!E5)+(Days!H13*Sheet1!G5)+(Days!I13*Sheet1!I5))/(Days!F13+Days!G13+Days!H13+Days!I13,""))))))

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but if any of F13 is zero, it will ignore G13, H13, and I13 and just choose Sheet1!C5.  Likewise, if G13 is zero, it ignores H13 and I13 and chooses Sheet1!E5. I do not think that is the goal since if all of them are not zero, you compute a formula.  I think what you may want something different based on which values are zero.  Perhaps you want something more like IF(F13=0,Sheet1!C5,F13*Sheet1!C5)+IF(G13=0,Sheet1!E5,G13*sHEET1!E5_+.... with something similar in the denominator.  Like I said, I am not sure I understand the formula.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand what's going on either, but wouldn't using a `VLOOKUP` to get cycle times and multiplying by the number of units produced do the job?

Comment: Yes I figured the formula I used is a bit weird. What I am getting to is: if any there is any number present in the F13 to I13 (a number should be present in any one of them), including a zero, it should show the respective cycle time.

Comment: Thank you @FocusWiz, cybernetic.nomad. I was able to get to what i needed.I used the following: 

=IF(F12<>"",'Cycle times'!C4,IF(Days!G12<>"",'Cycle times'!E4,IF(Days!H12<>"",'Cycle times'!G4,IF(Days!I12<>"",'Cycle times'!I4,"")))).  

It was very simple. Thank you!